# Is there any downside to ignoring 'raider troubles/ghoul problem' missions?

Tags: fallout-4

I seem to get a non-stop flow of Raider Troubles, Ghoul Problems, and Kidnapping missions--there seems to always be one or two that want my attention. They're kind of irritating, and I was curious if there's any downside to just ignoring them and letting them fail.

Comment: Actually it's not a duplicate. I'm not talking about settlements getting attacked, I'm talking about the kidnappings, ghoul problems and raider troubles missions. NOT the settlement is being attacked missions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get a mission like those, I'm assuming you're talking about the ones that pop up randomly. Those are for settlements that you already established that need aid. The only downside to ignoring these missions is that if you don't complete them within a certain amount of time, a settlement gets a few people killed and happiness goes down.

Comment: ah bugger. Losing settlers kind of sucks. Does that happen for raider/ghoul problems? Or only for the 'help defend' missions?

Comment: @Ted For the missions you get from Preston there is no penalty for not doing them. Those are to set up new settlements. The raider/ghoul problems make you lose settlers.

Comment: Doesn't this answer only apply to the "Help defend _[settlement]_" missions? Aren't they different from the "Ghoul troubles at Oberland Station" kind of missions? The "Help defend" ones need to be done in a certain time, but not the others.

Comment: @OGCthulu the endless raider/ghoul missions I get *are* from Preston, despite the fact I've unlocked the settlements already. Kind of like maintenance missions. He always has a new one when I report back to him. I've probably done 20 for sanctuary hills and Abernathy farm. And to broomstick--ghoul/raider missions have a time limit, just like the help defene missions.